# What is the $\lim_{z\rightarrow{\infty}}e^{-(z+i)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I'm struggling to find the following $complex$ limit (or show that it DNE): $\lim_{z\rightarrow{\infty}}e^{-(z+i)^2}$.

I know that we are actually looking at $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow{\infty}}e^{-(z+i)^2}$ where $|z|$ is the modulus of $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

For example $\lim_{z\rightarrow{\infty}}e^{-z}$ does not exist because $\lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}}e^{-x} \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow{-\infty}}e^{-x}$ (where $z$ is taken $z=x+0i)$.

I tried to do a similar thing in this problem but it doesn't work. Anny ideas here, does the limit exist and can we use a theorem or do we need to go back to the definition?

Comment: It looks like a shifted Gaussian bell....

Comment: Yes that's true! But this is the complex case.

Comment: I don't know a lot about complex limits.....but can you translate or draw analogy to the real case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That limit does not exist, because if $z$ is of the form $-i+\lambda$, with $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, then the limit is $0$. But if $z$ is of the form $-i+\lambda i$, with $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, then the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you José!

Comment: Can you say that you translated it to a real function by eliminating the imaginary part?.......I don't know about complex limits, so is this a standard approach (i.e. converting to real function)?

Comment: I would rather say that what I did was to *restrict* the function to sets on which its behaviour was easy to study. And, yes, on those sets it only takes real values.

Comment: @SaketGurjar You just show that if you approach $\infty$ from different ways in the complex plane you get different results for the limit and hence $the$ limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $z = ix$ for real $x$,
as $x \to \infty$,
$(z+i)^2
=(ix+i)^2
=-(x+1)^2
$
so
$e^{-(z+i)^2}
\to \infty$.

If $z = x-i$ for real $x$,
as $x \to \infty$,
$(z+i)^2
=(x-i+i)^2
=x^2
$
so
$e^{-(z+i)^2}
\to 0$.

Therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for answering Marty :)